# twilio whats app bot select one option from list

Tags: api, twilio, chatbot, whatsapp, whatsapi

i'm doing this whatsApp bot auto response using twilio apis,
i want user to select one option from list as shown in this pics, i check this link :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/interactive-messages/

it's called List Messages, so i want exactly  what is shown in the pics using twilio apis,
as i check this document (Creating templates with buttons) from twilio link : https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/buttons#additional-information,

i want button shows popup select one option  please help, i'm trying my best to ask this question the best i can i hope u understand after editing

[image]
click on it then this popup shows

[image]

thanks advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These messages are called [Interactive Messages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/interactive-messages/) and according to Meta's docs "users cannot select more than one option at the same time from a list or button message, but they can go back and re-open a previous message."

Please have a look at the [Twilio Doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/buttons#additional-information) to see which message types are currently supported.

Comment: i only want user to select one option my bad the way i asked this question, i just want to do exactly what shown in the pics

Comment: i will edit my question, i checked twilio Template and now i understand what i want , List Messages: Messages including a menu of up to 10 options. This type of message offers a simpler and more consistent way for users to make a selection when interacting with a business.